# "And don't you polish up well!"

Tags: meaning-in-context

(From *A Terrible Kindness* by Jo Browning Wroe)

*The dinner party. ***They have had a sumptuous meal*** and now Mr. David Melling, the president of the Institute, is addressing the party:*

> 'Ladies and gentlemen, I hope you've enjoyed tonight's feast.' David Melling smiles. **'And don't you polish up well!'** He brandishes a piece of paper. ' I have my dance card here, ladies, though you may have to form a queue, so please be patient.'
>
> Once the laughter dies down, Mr Melling talks, William notes, for eight minutes and ten seconds about the high standards of the institute, its charity work its growing international reputation.....

Does this phrasing mean something like in the rhyme

*"Jack Sprat could eat no fat, his wife could eat no lean*

*and so between them both, you see, they licked the platter clean."* ?

What does it mean literally *in this context*?

Comment: "Don't you polish up well" is an expression, an idiom. It's not literal.  It's a bit like saying "you don't normally look so well dressed, but well done for making an effort." - usually said as a joke, or as a slightly humorous insult.

Comment: Can you say how that might relate to the rhyme 'Jack Sprat could eat no fat…'? How could they be connected?

Comment: I think Billy Kerr's being a lot harsh, there.

Yes, '… don't you polish up well!' is an idiom, and clearly not literal and often said with humour but in more than 60 years of listening I've never before heard it suggested that was said as a joke, or any kind of insult.

In my experience, it generally means 'Wow! You can look good when you want to…' with no slight hint of Billy's negative connotations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Imagine you have an old piece of furniture.  It looks dark and shabby and not very beautiful.  But if you clean it and polish it you see that it is very good.  You might say that the piece of furniture "polishes up well".  It looks much better after being polished.

By extension, imagine a person who appears to be rough and not very good-looking, but when they wash, comb their hair, and put on nice clothes you can see that they are actually quite beautiful, you would say that the person "polishes up well".  You would normally use it about someone whose job or position in society means that they are often dirty or can only afford old clothes.

So it is not connected to the expression "polish off ones food", and has nothing to do with the nursery rhyme. He does not mean "you have eaten up all your food".

So David is making a small joke about the other guests.  He is saying that they look very good in their smart clothes (and therefore implying that they are usually rather rough).
He then goes on to make a joke about himself, ironically suggesting that there will be a queue of people wanting to dance with him. It's irony because we expect that the opposite is the case. Because it is irony, the guests understand that he is making a joke and respond with laughter (if taken literally, what he says is almost obnoxiously rude and self-congratulatory and would be met not with laughter but with howls of derision)

This kind of joke and (self) depreciation is common in such ***after-dinner speeches.***

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake when editing.

Comment: Note that a more common way to say this, at least in the UK, is "don't you **scrub up** well."

Comment: **The very first comment - corrected:** @ James K - Thank you very much. There is a question: Doesn't the last sentence but one have to be "It's irony because we *know/insinuate* that the opposite is the case" - or something like that? -

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman - Then, why don't you upvote this answer?

Comment: The usual idiom which this author is playing with is: Don't you **clean up well?**

Comment: @Lambie "Well, I never thought she’d clean up as good looking as that, Governor. She’s a credit to me, ain’t she?"  [Pygmalian](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/3825/3825-h/3825-h.htm") by George Bernard Shaw, 1912.

Comment: Good reference, but the link is incorrectly set up, it has a stray double-quote at the end. It should go here: https://www.gutenberg.org/files/3825/3825-h/3825-h.htm ... also *Pygmalion* rather than *-an*.

Comment: So nicely explained.

Comment: @Lambie I can't agree with that.  Exactly as DanielR points out there are many variations.  "clean up" is not the "usual" one.

Comment: @Fattie Clean  up nicely, clean up well. scrub up plays off of that, doesn't it? Of course, the Pygmalian quote is charming, I agree.

Comment: I think it's worth nothing that the phrase **is not in any way self-deprecating**.  Like (any utterance, particularly in English) it can be used in a wildly positive way, a wholly sarcastic way, a kind but self-deprecating way, a seethingly bitter yet self-deprecating way, and so on.

Comment: @Lambie I really appreciate that in some cases there's **an idiom** (say, "pigs may fly")  And then someone appears on here asking about an utterance, an utterance said uniquely and exceptionally by some author, (example "assholes may fly!") and the answer has two steps.  (STEP 1), foreign speaker, first we must tell you that "pigs may fly" is an idiom.  (STEP 2) now we explain to you that the OP phrase is the author playing with the idiom from step 1. That is not the situation in this question. All of the variations mentioned are variations, there is no "primary" and the one in the OP is ..

Comment: .. extremely commonplace (probably as much as all the others), the author is not referring to or playing off "a common idiom". It *is* a common idiom.  If the OP phrase was **"don't you guys angle-grinder up nicely!"** [perhaps regarding some androids in a sci-fi say) then indeed that would be *the author is playing off don't you polish up nicely* (Clever, right? : ) )

Comment: @Fattie polish up well  is playing off of: clean up nicely. And in fact this is the second question re the author who seems to know how to avoid clichés.

Comment: @Lambie  I think poliish-up, scrub-up and clean-up are all possible variation of this saying. My feeling is that "polish-up" is at least as common as the other variations.

Comment: @Fattie  it would be *such* an obnoxiously self-congratulatory thing to say literally, that the *only* possible way it could be understood is ironically.  The irony is so thick that I would understand it as being clearly self-deprecating. This is supported by the fact that it is met with "laughs" and not howls of derision.  But I shall edit to make that clear.

Comment: Perhaps this is a regionalism. I've heard "clean up well" many times. I've never heard "polish up well". Being familiar with "clean up well" makes it possible to instantly understand "polish up well". But if "polish up well" is an established idiom ... not among people I talk to.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom means "You look good when well-dressed."

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted James K's answer and I won't repeat it. Let me just add one point:

"Polish" has at least two distinct meanings. To "polish something off" is to complete it. This is perhaps mostly used in the context of eating, as in, "I was so hungry I polished off an entire roast chicken."

"Polish" can also mean the act of cleaning and usually applying chemicals to wood, metal, or whatever material to make it look new and shiny and pretty.

(I haven't checked the etymology of these two meanings. Maybe they're related and maybe not.)

In this case, the writer is using definition #1.

Comment: My guess would be that polishing off your plate means eating everything and leaving the plate clean and shiny: looking like it's been polished. But [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/polish) gives a different origin: polishing is the last step in furniture making, so to "polish something off" is to complete it, and the phrase is first attested in pugilism, of all places!